# Error with RKPaginator when loading next page in success block

Tags: restkit, restkit-0.20

I try to load all pages of an api using Restkit and RKPaginator (I don't know the number of pages before loading the first page).

1 out of 10 tries, I get the following error

'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Cannot perform a load while one is already in progress.'

When this problem do not raise, the function is working as expected

I am using the following code:

```c
- (void)loadAllPagesForEntity:(NSString*)entityName
                      success:(void (^)(RKPaginator *paginator, NSArray *objects, NSUInteger page))success
{
    URObjectManager *objectManager = [URObjectManager sharedManager];

    NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?page=:currentPage&size=:perPage",entityName];

    RKPaginator* myPaginator = (RKPaginator*)[objectManager paginatorWithPathPattern:requestString];
    myPaginator.perPage = 50; // this will request /posts?page=N&per_page=20

    [myPaginator setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKPaginator *paginator, NSArray *objects, NSUInteger page)
     {
          if ([paginator hasNextPage]) { [paginator loadNextPage]; }
         else if (success) { success(paginator, objects, page); }
     }
     failure:^(RKPaginator *paginator, NSError *error)
     {
         NSLog(@"Failure: %@", error);
     }];

    [myPaginator loadPage:0];
}
```

This code is called on more entities:

```c
[self loadAllPagesForEntity:@"entity1" success:nil];
[self loadAllPagesForEntity:@"entity2" success:nil];
```

...

```c
[self loadAllPagesForEntity:@"entity n" success:nil];
```

My program crashes and is blocked by one of the following assert in RKPaginator.m:
l.158

```c
NSAssert(self.isLoaded, @"Cannot determine hasNextPage: paginator is not loaded.");
```

or

l.177

```c
NSAssert(! self.objectRequestOperation, @"Cannot perform a load while one is already in progress.");
```

Is it not correct to test hasNextPage or perform loadNextPage within the success block ?
What would be the correct way to do it ?

I have tried without success to use :

```c
[paginator performSelector:@selector(loadNextPage) onThread:[NSThread currentThread] withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Performing selector after a delay corrected the problem but is not an acceptable solution.

Comment: How many of these are you running at the same time? Have you done anything with the operation queue? iOS? OSX?

Comment: I download about 10 entities in 20 pages on ios7 / ipad. I don't use operation queue (but Restkit use it under the ground isn't it ?). I do also try to init the download of the 20 pages inside a loop using getObjectAtPath with page as parameter  and don't face any problem (except that the number of page is fixed).

Comment: If the request finishes in success then you should be able to start the next page. I'd turn on trace log. Log the server response. And change the `[objectManager.operationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:5];`

Comment: Setting concurrentOperation did not have effect. Seems like a bug in RKPaginator, success callback is called before isLoaded is reset. I will post a fix as answer.

Comment: Recommend raising it on the RestKit github page too.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a bug in RKPaginator.m (Restkit 0.23). I will fill a request on github as soon as I find time.

It seems like the success callback and the finishing of request operation are not done in the same thread.

So, when success is called, isLoaded is not always set.

I changed the code to always call the finishing of operation before executing success callback. 
It did the trick for me.

comment l.198

```
// Add KVO to ensure notification of loaded state prior to execution of completion block
//[self.objectRequestOperation addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"isFinished" options:0 context:nil];
```

l.221

```
[self.objectRequestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    [self operationFinished];

    if (self.successBlock) {
        self.successBlock(self, [mappingResult array], self.currentPage);            
    }
}
```

Add function

```
-(void)operationFinished
{
    RKObjectRequestOperation*oro = self.objectRequestOperation;
    self.objectRequestOperation = nil;

    self.loaded = (oro.mappingResult != nil);
    self.mappingResult = oro.mappingResult;
    self.error = oro.error;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted solution with tests on RestKit github page. 
I hope it will be merge soon, but if you need it now feel free to use my fork.

https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/pull/2156

:)